# Does Angular CLI use SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I typed `dir /s/b systemjs.config.js` into the Windows command line from the root directory of a new Angular app that was installed by Angular CLI, but the Windows command line responded by saying `File Not Found.`

Is SystemJS installed by default by Angular CLI?  If yes, how do I find its config file?  If not, what is used instead?

Comment: No, it's used webpack for a while: https://medium.com/@jeff.boothe/angular-cli-meets-webpack-7c9b1a1e1e89

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you feel like writing that out as an answer, I would be happy to accept it and mark it as accepted.  It would be nice if you showed how to find the webpack config file along the way.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be terribly useful, it's not clear why you were looking for `systemjs.config.js` in the first place. There isn't a webpack config file unless you [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject).

Comment: Hi. To see the files used internally, you can use ng eject or ng eject - - prod. Note that after you need to remove ejected = true to build and run inside angular cli again

Comment: @AndresM Thank you. From where do you remove 'ejected=true'?

Comment: angular-cli.json. You may also need to do eject --force if it tells you there is already a package.json file with scripts

Comment: I'm not the guardian of the Big Webpack Secret, this is common knowledge; *"stole"* is profoundly unhelpful hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI does not use SystemJS anymore. They have moved over to Webpack, so there will not be a `systemjs.config.js` file in your project.